# Selfshadow plane affected by a displacement map not working

Tags: three.js

Working on some kind of fictional treasure map. I'm cutting a large displacement map intosmaller tiles as I don't yet how wide the final terrain is going to be -- right now it's 5*5, but it could be wider in the future

For some reasons, I am having issues projecting shadows on the displaced planes.
I don't know where the problem is coming from. Maybe it's the way I push meshes into an array through a function, i'm afraid i'm not doing this the right way.

I'd like to achieve the result using a directional light

[Here is a c4d draft of what i'm trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAA3l.jpg)

[and here is what i'm able to do in the browser (didnt manage to tile them properly yet :^)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQ4iy.png)

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

var material = [];
var texture = [];
var tile = [];

var planeRes = 128;
var planesize = 1;

var dim = 5;
var size = dim * dim;

var DispScale = 2;

var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planesize,planesize,planeRes, planeRes);


function tileGenerator(inc) {
  if (inc < 10) {
    texture[inc] = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('cut25lowres/image_part_00' + inc + '.jpg');
  } else {
    texture[inc] = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('cut25lowres/image_part_0' + inc + '.jpg');
  }
  material[inc] = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
    color: 0xffffff,
    displacementMap: texture[inc],
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    receiveShadow : true,
    castShadow : true
  });
  tile[inc] = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material[inc]);
}

for (var i = 1; i < size + 1; i++) {
  tileGenerator(i);
}


for (var i = 1; i < size + 1; i++) {
  tile[i].position.set(-planesize * (i % dim)+1, 0, -planesize * Math.ceil(i / dim)+1 );
  tile[i].rotation.x = Math.PI / 2 + Math.PI;
  tile[i].rotation.z = Math.PI / 2;

  scene.add(tile[i]);
}

var dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1 );
dirLight.castShadow = true;

dirLight.shadow.camera.near = 0.1;
dirLight.shadow.camera.far = 6;
dirLight.shadow.mapSize.set( 1024, 1024 );
var targetObject = new THREE.Object3D();
targetObject.position.x = -10;
targetObject.position.z = -10;

dirLight.position.y = 3;

scene.add(targetObject);

dirLight.target = targetObject;
scene.add( dirLight );
```

Edit : Here is a cleaner version without the array as it's not part of the problem
jsfiddle.net/clemtre/3y9tqc6j/34

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap;

renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();

var heightmap = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('https://i.imgur.com/MVYhfd7.jpeg');
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(20, 20, 100, 100);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0xffffff,
  displacementMap: heightmap,
  displacementScale: 10
});


var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
light.position.set(0, 1, 1).normalize();
light.castShadow = true;
scene.add(light);

var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
plane.rotation.x = -Math.PI/2;
scene.add(plane);

camera.position.z = -20;
camera.position.y = 5;
controls.update();

var animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  controls.update();

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

animate();
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you add a working demo? Either via jsfiddle or [a code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: Here it is : https://jsfiddle.net/clemtre/3y9tqc6j/34/